# What is $\frac{9}{3} - \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I need to compute $\frac{9}{3} - \frac{1}{2}$.

I got an answer of $\frac{8}{6}$ but that is incorrect.  $\frac{5}{2}$ is the correct answer. How is this possible?

Comment: Nine thirds - 1 half's  fraction

Comment: 3.0-.5=2.5 in my world of decimals. 2.5 would also be 2 and a half or 5 halves.

Comment: You should have shown your working, because other people cannot figure out how you got $\frac{8}{6}$.

Comment: @user21820 $\frac 86=\frac {9-1}{2\cdot 3}$ is obtained when you don't properly put the two fractions over a common denominator before subtracting.

Comment: @user21820 As Mark Bennet showed, in this case it was easy to figure out how the mistake was made.  The user found the correct common denominator, but forgot to multiply the numerator by the necessary factor before subtracting.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Ah I see. But then the problem is not with the mistake in using the method but with the understanding. No one would do that unless they didn't quite know what fractions mean, except for careless mistakes of course..

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac93-\frac12=3-\frac12=\frac62-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{2}$$

$$\text{or}$$

$$\frac93-\frac12=\frac{9\times2-3\times1}{6}=\frac{15}{6}=\frac{5}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

So we are trying to compute $\frac{9}{3} - \frac{1}{2}$.  To add or subtract fractions, we need to find a common denominator.  I think you already understand that the common denominator here is $6$.

To get a $6$ in the denominator of $\frac{9}{3}$, we need to multiply this by $\frac{2}{2}$, and so this becomes $\frac{18}{6}$.  To get a $6$ in the denominator of $\frac{1}{2}$, we need to multiply this by $\frac{3}{3}$, and we get $\frac{3}{6}$.

So, we get

$\frac{9}{3} - \frac{1}{2}$

$ = \frac{9}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{3}$

$ = \frac{18}{6} - \frac{3}{6}$

$= \frac{18 - 3}{6} $

$ = \frac{15}{6}$

But the numerator and denominator have a common factor of $3$, since $15 = 5 \cdot 3$ and $6 = 2 \cdot 3$, so we can cancel the $3$s, and we get:

$\frac{15}{6}$

$= \frac{5 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 3}$

$= \frac{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that fraction, first simplify $9\over 3$ to $3$ and then do $3-{1\over 2}$, which is six halves minus one half, which is why you get $5\over 2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's like subtracting $\frac {1}{2}$ from $3$, so you get $2.5$